# How to flip the function f(x) about y-axis

Tags: functions, pure-function

Suppose I have a function `W(x)`. I wanted to flip (reflect) this function about the y-axis. I tried plotting `W(-x)` but it is not giving the expected results.

```
L = 4;
beta1 = {0.468776, 1.17352, 1.96369, 2.74889, 3.53429, 4.31969, 
  5.10509, 5.89049, 6.67588, 7.46128, 8.24668, 9.03208, 9.81748}
W = ((Cos[b*x] - 
      Cosh[b*x]) - (((Cos[b*L] + Cosh[b*L])/(Sin[b*L] + 
         Sinh[b*L]))*(Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x]))) /. b -> beta1[[1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
W[x_] := ((Cos[b*x] - Cosh[b*x]) - (((Cos[b*L] + Cosh[b*L])/(Sin[b*L] + 
          Sinh[b*L]))*(Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x]))) /. b -> beta1[[1]]

plt = Plot[W[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}];
```

**1.** Use the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}`

```
Show[plt, 
 Plot[W[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**2.** Post-process the output to transform lines:

```
Show[plt, plt /. Line[x_] :> {Red, Line[{-1, 1} # & /@ x]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Alternatively, use [`ReflectionTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReflectionTransform.html):

```
Show[plt, 
 plt /. L_Line :> {Red, GeometricTransformation[L, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**3.** Use `ParametricPlot` with `{-x, W[x]}}` as the first argument:

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, W[x]}, {-x, W[x]}}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}]
```

or

```
Show[ParametricPlot[{x, W[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}], 
 ParametricPlot[{-x, W[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Reply the comment**

```
L = 4;
beta1 = {0.468776, 1.17352, 1.96369, 2.74889, 3.53429, 4.31969, 
   5.10509, 5.89049, 6.67588, 7.46128, 8.24668, 9.03208, 9.81748};
w[x_] := ((Cos[b*x] - 
      Cosh[b*x]) - (((Cos[b*L] + Cosh[b*L])/(Sin[b*L] + 
          Sinh[b*L]))*(Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x])));
interval = Interval[{-3, 2 Pi}];
{Plot[Table[w[x], {b, beta1}] // Evaluate, x ∈ interval],
  Plot[Table[w[-x], {b, beta1}] // Evaluate, 
   x ∈ -interval]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

```
L = 4;
beta1 = {0.468776, 1.17352, 1.96369, 2.74889, 3.53429, 4.31969, 
   5.10509, 5.89049, 6.67588, 7.46128, 8.24668, 9.03208, 9.81748};
w[x_] := ((Cos[b*x] - 
       Cosh[b*x]) - (((Cos[b*L] + Cosh[b*L])/(Sin[b*L] + 
           Sinh[b*L]))*(Sin[b*x] - Sinh[b*x]))) /. b -> beta1[[1]];
interval = Interval[{-3, 2 Pi}];
Show[Plot[w[x], x ∈ interval, PlotStyle -> Green], 
 Plot[w[-x], x ∈ -interval, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Your suggestion is not working, If you try plotting from 0 to L you will some to know.

Comment: @acoustics see the updated `Interval`

Comment: See if you change the `beta1[[1]]` to `beta[[2]]` it won't work. I tried it, It fails as I change the value of `b`

Comment: @acoustics It work fine. Here we plot all the `b`,see the updated.